# How does this button make the piston work?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

If you set up a button, a piston and a redstone dust in this composition...

[image]

The piston will be activated while the button is on (and will retract when off).

[image]

However, I can't find the rationale why this gadget works. I guess this is some kind of BUD mechanism, but still don't understand what route the piston is powered through.

As far as I know, if I remove the dust below the button, it'll no longer trigger the piston.

[image]

Nor when the dust is powered otherly.

[image]

Comment: @ppperry Thanks, that post doesn't particularly answer me but [the article they cite](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Tutorials/Quasi-connectivity) does. It seems that the chunk of information added to that article in last year's July provides the clear explanation why my formation works.

Answer (score 3):

This is a block update phenomenon. The button is providing diagonal (BUD) power to the piston, and the redstone dust is providing updates to the piston, which causes it to extend. Normally, block updates are only triggered on the 5 sides of a piston. However, redstone updates are special, and can provide updates to a piston 2 blocks away.

The dust doesn't provide any power to the piston (which is why the piston doesn't extend with just the dust in this configuration), however, it does provide a necessary update to the piston (which is why the piston doesn't extend without it).

Comment: Do you mean redstone updates also affect blocks in diagonal positions?

Comment: I believe it's a 2 block radius, particular to redstone updates (including placing redstone. Block updates are weird)

Comment: Thanks. I tried a bit and I think I understand that at least redstone torch and dust act the same way on update. Do you know any source referring to this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

This is called quasi-connectivity, it is a property that is shared by pistons, droppers and dispensers. Basically, what it means is that the redstone appliances that are effected by this phenomenon can be activated by having the block above them powered, this includes air blocks. This may seem like a bug, but the team at Mojang have stated that [it is a feature that works as intended](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-108). It sometimes causes trouble in circuitry, however it is the premise that many piston doors work on. Without this feature, flush piston doors would be incredibly complex and difficult to build.

You can find more information on the subject, as well as tutorials, on the [Minecraft Wiki.](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Quasi-connectivity)

Comment: Yeah, I think this "feature" will be going away at some point. It most certainly is a bug, but it isn't necessarily easy to fix without breaking a bunch of other things.

Comment: @MBraedley this is not the case, this was intentionally added by the developers, and is essential in many contraptions. It is not going to be removed

Comment: Cite your sources.  It was introduced because it fixed another redstone bug, and was kept because it was more desirable than the bug it fixed.

Comment: The developers have stated "It works as intended"

Comment: Do  you not understand what "cite your sources" means?  Show me where they say it works as intended.  Additionally, just because something works as intended doesn't mean that it isn't a bug.  If they could fix it without breaking _all of redstone_, they probably would.

Comment: Read my post and you will find a link to the Minecraft Wiki where it says "While quasi-connectivity can be difficult to work around sometimes and might seem like a bug, it is officially recognized as a feature that 'works as intended' and does make some builds much easier"

Comment: I'm a little confused (after reading the wiki article). Which component do you think triggers the quasi-connectivity in this case? The button or the dust?

Comment: A wiki is not generally a citeable source, since they're globally editable and anyone can add unverified text. In this case the wiki itself had a reference to the actual bug with Mojang. I've edited that into the answer to make it more standalone.